# C# Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have plain text file (`.txt`) which has some expressions and I want to replace invalid expression with... ...let's say zero.

An invalid expression is expression which contains `1+3^4^5` or `10+3+4*5+2^5^6^7`, i.e. an expression can't contain `number^number^number^...`, it can only contain `number^number`.

I understand that best way to do this is to use Regex but I dont know how to write this in regex.

Comment: What is separating these "expressions"?

Comment: If you don't know how to write a regular expression, then perhaps this is not the best way. Why not take your expression as a string and `Split()` it on `^`. If there are more than two elements returned, then your expression is invalid.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: That won't work for `1^2+3^4`.

Comment: @minitech: True enough. Some more work is cleary required :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression that will detect multiple powers is

```
(\d+\^){2,}
```

(`{2,}` means two or more times in a row)

---

Just ran the following Test:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace SampleNamespace
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string line = "1+3^4^5  10+3+4*5+2^5^6^7";              
            System.Console.WriteLine(line);
            line = Regex.Replace(line, @"(\d+\^){2,}", "0");
            System.Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Output was:

```
>RegexTest.exe
1+3^4^5  10+3+4*5+2^5^6^7
1+05  10+3+4*5+07
```

It failed to replace the trailing \d but it does work. You can grab the trailing \d with the following correction to the regex:

```
(\d+\^){2,}\d+
```

---

If you want to wipe out the entire expression that contains a double power just use

```
.*(\d+\^){2,}.*
```

in your replace expresion. The `.*` on either side will swallow up the entire string surrounding the double power when a replacement takes place.

Comment: That won't work. `^` is a special character in regular expressions. Escape it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but when i tried to replace line which contains that expression, nothing changed, the code is  `var line = streamReader.ReadToEnd();


            line = Regex.Replace(line, @"(\d+\^){2,}", "0");

            streamWriter.Write(line);`

Comment: @hyperN: With a minor adjustment, yes, it appears to work: http://ideone.com/Kq7Ez. Are you sure your input is what you think it is?

Comment: @hyperN See the edit in the answer - it does work. There must be some weird encoding or something. Do a streamWriter.WritLine(line) before the change and paste exactly what you're running the replacement on.

Comment: @minitech it's like we're living identical timelines :p Except I ran my test in compilr: http://compilr.com/alainbryden/regextest

Comment: @Alain Output is correct =) obviously I didn't explain well enough what I need. how can I replace whole line which contains (\d+\^){2,}\d+ whit zero, so intput is: `1+3^4^5  10+3+4*5+2^5^6^7` and output should be `0`, not `1+05  10+3+4*5+07`

Comment: Oh, if you want to wipe out the entire expression just use '`.*(\d+\^){2,}.*`' in your replace expresion. The `.*` on either side will swallow up the entire string surrounding the double power. Sorry for the confusion - the intent wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regular expression for that:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+\^){2}");

...

if(re.IsMatch(myData)) {
    // It's not valid
}
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted; however `{2}` matches only 2 repetitions. You should use `{2,}`, which means "two or more times".

Comment: Can't be sure, but it seems someone might have **erroneously** determined that your expression would not match (and thus would not reject) an expression with `2^5^6^7` -- however, I'm pretty sure it _would_ match a _string_ that contains that, so... maybe just being spiteful? got me... - I'll +1 for what looks like a valid solution to me :)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: That doesn't matter; `a^b^` is a subset of `a^b^c^`.

Comment: The OP wants to replace the invalid expression. If he wants to do so, he will have to find the whole expression, not just a part of it.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I swear that wasn't part of the question when I answered :)

Comment: I +1'd. Someone must have misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Downvoted because the regex does not match '3^4^5' of the invalid expression '1+3^4^5' given in the question but matches '3^4^'. In case that would be replaced with 'zero' (like stated in the question) the expression '1+5' would be generated. Not quite correct. So the expression does not work with input patterns containing an odd sequence of \d+\^

Comment: @Saintedlama: Yeah, I thought the OP just wanted to *match* invalid strings, not replace them. EDIT: Checking the comments on the accepted answer, that *is* what the OP wanted. Sigh...